# Return Vertices In Undirected Graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, undirected-graph

I am trying to come up with a greedy algorithm in Python that returns the vertices in an undirected graph given a certain starting vertex.  I understand that DFS determines if a cycle exists, but I am trying to actually return the vertices that form the cycle.  I am using an adjacency matrix to represent the following graph:

```
adjacencyMatrix = [[0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

pictorially this is an undirected graph comprised of a single cycle.

My current thought process is to set my starting index to the first `1` I come across (In this case `adjacencyMatrix[0][1]`).  Then I would look at the rest of the row to see if another `1` was there, because that means my current vertex is connected to that index.  However, I am not entirely sure if (a) this is the right approach and (b) how to "move" to the next vertex.  For example, how would I navigate my nested `for` loop to move from the `adjacencyMatrix[0][1]` vertex to the `adjacencyMatrix[0][2]` vertex? Would I just swap the row and column indices?

**EDIT**
This solution I came up with seems to work for the few graphs I tried it on:

```
def findCycle(matrix):
    visited = list()
    cycleNotFound = True
    row = 0
    col = 0
    startVertex = (0, 0)

    while cycleNotFound:

        # Only add a vertex if it has not already been visited
        if (matrix[row][col] == 1) and ((row, col) not in visited):
            # Set the startVertex when the first node is found
            if len(visited) == 0:
                startVertex = (row, col)

            # Add the current vertex and its counter part
            visited.append((row, col))
            visited.append((col, row))

            # If row and col are equal, infite loop will get created
            if row != col:
                row = col
                col = 0
            else:
                row += 1

        # If back at starting point, break look
        elif ((row, col) == startVertex) and (len(visited) > 1):
            cycleNotFound = False
            visited.append(startVertex)

        # Else, continue to look for unvisted neighbors
        else:
            col += 1

    return visited

if __name__ == "__main__":
    matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]]
    cycle = findCycle(matrix)
    index = 0
    # Print the vertices.  Only print even vertices to avoid duplicates.
    while (index < len(cycle)):
        print cycle[index]
        index += 2
```

it is not the most elegant solution and I'm sure there is some major refactoring that needs to be done.

Comment: If you're doing DFS you go to one of your neighbors recursively, after finishing DFS from this neighbor you move on to the next neighbors etc.

Comment: Okay, so would I just first run DFS to determine if a cycle exists and then use a slightly modified DFS method to return all of the visited vertices?

Comment: First of, the adjacency matrix is symmetrical. The number of vertices is defined by the size of the matrix. A matrix of size `n x n` means that there are `n` vertices. To list vertices connected to a certain vertex check the corresponding row for ones, their indices "are" the vertices you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
def findCycle(node):
    cycle = stack()
    if( DFS(node, cycle) ):
        return cycle
    return None

def DFS(node, cycle):
    cycle.append(node)
    mark node as visited
    foreach node.neighbors as neighbor:
        if neighbor already visited:
            return true
        else:
            if( DFS(neighbor, cycle) ) return true
    cycle.remove(node)
    return false
```

Comment: Okay, this actually might be similar to what I am currently working on.  I assume the `neighbors` function would return a list of the column numbers for each `[row][col] == 1`? For instance using the provided adjacency matrix `1.neighbors` would return `[2, 3]`?

Comment: @steveclark hi, please choose my answer if you find it correct. Thx

Comment: I wasn't able to implement your solution and since I suck at debugging recursion I decided to continue working on the one I was already working on.  I posted the code for my solution in the question as an edit.

Comment: @TobyD:  I think `findCycle` can return the wrong nodes.  `DFS` doesn't add the already-marked node to `cycle` (although it could be found among the top node's neighbors, hopefully still marked).  Worse, it includes nodes in `cycle` that _aren't_ part of the cycle.  Consider a cycle A->B->C->B:  The nodes popped off of `cycle` will be: C, B, A.  If `DFS` pushed B onto `cycle` before returning `True`, `findCycle` could pop and `yield` B, and then continue popping and `yield`ing until B showed up again.  But without the "guilty" node on top of the stack, `findCycle` has some sleuthing to do.